# Node.JS and run-applescript npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, applescript

Novice coder and completely new to (node)JavaScript...

I cannot seem to get this working... any suggestions?

**Initial Steps:**

directory: **/Users/me/JavaScriptPlayground/AS-JS.js**

```js
var runAppleScript = require('run-applescript')
(async () => {
let appleScript = `
    display dialog "yo im talking to you"
    `;
let result = await runAppleScript(appleScript);
})();
```

I ran [npm i run-applescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-applescript)

```
me@my-MBP JavaScriptPlayground % npm i run-applescript

up to date, audited 22 packages in 682ms

5 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities`
```

then saved the code **AS-JS.js** *to be sure...* and ran this:
*(note: in the steps I took, I changed the file name to index.js)*

```
Node.js v18.15.0
me@my-MBP JavaScriptPlayground % node AS-JS.js
```

**message:**

```
/Users/me/JavaScriptPlayground/AS-JS.js:1
var runAppleScript = require('run-applescript')
                     ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/me/JavaScriptPlayground/node_modules/run-applescript/index.js from /Users/me/JavaScriptPlayground/AS-JS.js not supported.
index.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /Users/me/JavaScriptPlayground/node_modules/run-applescript/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/JavaScriptPlayground/AS-JS.js:1:22) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

**My steps:**

1. so scratch the AS-JS.js script and I changed it to index.js
2. changed index.js to index.cjs in the /Users/me/JavaScriptPlayground/node_modules/run-applescript
   and changed the "import ... "'s in that file to "dynamic import ..."

> Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to
> use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules,

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:571
      throw e;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/me/JavaScriptPlayground/node_modules/run-applescript/index.js'
    at createEsmNotFoundErr (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:15)
    at finalizeEsmResolution (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:15)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:565:14)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:634:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/JavaScriptPlayground/index.js:1:22) *//also changed this index.js to index.cjs ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ idk im trying,...*
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: '/Users/me/JavaScriptPlayground/node_modules/run-applescript/package.json'
}
```

3. reverted everything back and tried the second remark *(and after that deleted and re-installed the run-applescript npm and did the same thing)*

> change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /Users/me/JavaScriptPlayground/node_modules/run-applescript/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

```
/Users/me/JavaScriptPlayground/node_modules/run-applescript/index.js:1
import process from 'node:process';
^^^^^^
**message**
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/JavaScriptPlayground/index.js:1:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
```

and tried to change my .js files to .mjs. still errors and there I gave up...

Oh and somewhere in there I googled it and someone said to revert to a previous version of something (sorry I forget...) so I ran the suggested npm i statement which gave me a severe error... so I did the fix statement... (should I be worried about this??)

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT**

Oh and I ran it through runkit on the npm site[image: image here]

Comment: See usage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-applescript

Comment: yeah I did. that's where I got this package(?) from- well the documentation to install I guess..
I can't even get it working in the runkit they have provided. I get the same errors